# Contract calling another contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

I am wondering how I could have a function in one contract call another contract and check to see if the calling contract was in fact the one that initiated the call, rather than checking for msg.sender. How could I do this?

I guess an example is that I have a contract that holds tokens and I would like that contract to approve a transferFrom function that allows another contract to transfer token on behalf of the contract. How do I do this while avoiding the role of msg.sender?

Comment: What's the problem with using msg.sender? Is the issue that you want to have another contract in between the owner of the tokens and the token contract?

Comment: Yes, that is the issue. The owner of the tokens is by another contract. I need to be able to have a user call a function that would transfer tokens from the current contract to another  contract. The user however would not actually hold any of the tokens, the contract would.

Comment: I was thinking something like this could work: `function approveSelfSpender(address _spender, uint _valuue) returns (bool success) {
    allowed[this][_spender] = _value;
    Approval(this, _spender, _value);
    return true;
  }
`

Comment: And then just have a function that allows a user that calls the function to spend the contracts tokens on the contracts behalf, like this `approveSelfSpender(msg.sender, balanceOf[this]);`

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `msg.sender` as a reliable means of authenticating the sender. I think what you're getting at is how to cope with the limitations of `msg.sender`; it reveals only the latest sender in a (possibly) long chain.

Consider another example:

`contractFactory` produces `FundRaiser` contracts with "`owner`" set to the originator who asked `contractFactory` to deploy a new contract. So, the transaction originator is a step removed from the deployed contract.

The usual approach wouldn't work:

```
owner = msg.sender;
```

That would set the new `FundRaiser` owner to the `contractFactory`. Not what we want. Since `msg.sender` isn't giving us the information we need, we'll have to pass it into the `FundRaiser` constructor, like:

```
function FundRaiser(address originator) {
    owner = originator;
}
```

The deploying function in the factory can pass it along, like:

```
function newCampaign() {
    FundRaiser f = new FundRaiser(msg.sender);
}
```

That way, the original `msg.sender` (and any other important information) ends up passed down the chain where it's needed.

Hope it helps.